# pandas asfreq returns NaN if exact date DNE

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Let's say I have financial data in a `pandas.Series`, called `fin_series.`

Here's a peek at `fin_series`.

```
In [565]: fin_series
Out[565]: 
Date
2008-05-16    1000.000000
2008-05-19    1001.651747
2008-05-20    1004.137434
...
2014-12-22    1158.085200
2014-12-23    1150.139126
2014-12-24    1148.934665
Name: Close, Length: 1665
```

I'm interested in looking at the quarterly endpoints of the data.  However, not all financial trading days fall exactly on the 'end of the quarter.'

For example:

```
In [566]: fin_series.asfreq('q')
Out[566]: 
2008-06-30     976.169624
2008-09-30     819.518923
2008-12-31     760.429261
...
2009-06-30     795.768956
2009-09-30     870.467121
2009-12-31     886.329978
...
2011-09-30     963.304679
2011-12-31            NaN
2012-03-31            NaN
....
2012-09-30            NaN
2012-12-31    1095.757137
2013-03-31            NaN
2013-06-30            NaN
...
2014-03-31    1138.548881
2014-06-30    1168.248194
2014-09-30    1147.000073
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Here's a little function that accomplishes what I'd like, along with the desired end result.

```
def bmg_qt_asfreq(series):
    ind = series[1:].index.quarter != series[:-1].index.quarter
    ind = numpy.append(ind, True)
    return tmp[ind]
```

which gives me:

```
In [15]: bmg_asfreq(tmp)
Out[15]: 
Date
2008-06-30     976.169425
2008-09-30     819.517607
2008-12-31     760.428770
... 
2011-09-30     963.252831
2011-12-30     999.742132
2012-03-30    1049.848583
...
2012-09-28    1086.689824
2012-12-31    1093.943357
2013-03-28    1117.111859
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Note that I'm preserving the dates of the "closest prior price," instead of simply using `pandas.asfreq(freq = 'q', method = 'ffill')`, as **the preservations of dates that exist within the original `Series.Index` is crucial.**

This seems like a silly problem that many people have had and must be addressed by all of the `pandas` time manipulation functionality, but I can't figure out how to do it with `resample` or `asfreq.`

Anyone who could show me the builtin `pandas` functionality to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Your 3-step solution seems to be the most viable and relatively simple to implement. Since this is more unique situation I can't think of any `pandonic` solutions.

Comment: @aus_lacy, I don't think this is that "unique," I run into this specific issue in financial data quite frequently. I'll post my function solve in a couple days, but it seems like a trivial issue that must have been solved on the `pandas` side, no?

Comment: It's possible that `pandas` has some functionality that will take care of this, but I'm not aware of anything. I'm by no means an expert in this domain though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is a <strike>dataframe</strike> `Series` , first do

```
import pandas as pd
fin_series.resample("q",pd.Series.last_valid_index)
```

to get a series with the last non-NA index for each quarter. Then

```
fin_series.resample("q","last")
```

for the last non-NA value. You can then join these together. As you suggested in your comment:

```
fin_series[fin_series.resample("q",pd.Series.last_valid_index)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Luciano, I just wanted to make sure there was a line in your response that generated a replica of the "desired outcome."

Answer (score 0):

```
df.asfreq('d').interpolate().asfreq('q')
```